# High Density Interval for skewed Distributions

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

I was wondering how to find "**2 types of 90% credible limits**" for my skewed distribution (see the code that produces my skewed distribution "below")?

In particular, I need the:

1-  Heights of the two points forming the credible limits to be **UNEQUAL**, BUT the **AREA** under their tails to be **EQUAL** (**Type 1**, the usual 90% CI)

2- Heights of the two points forming the credible limits to be **EQUAL**, BUT the **AREA** under their tails to be **UNEQUAL** (**Type 2**, the unusual 90% CI)

Here is the R code for my distribution:

```
N <- seq(from=100,to=2000,by=1)
P <- choose(N-100,50)/choose(N,60)

## Normalize Ps to make the total area under the curve become 1:
sum(P)
P <- P/sum(P)
plot(N,P,type="l")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  quantile(P, c(0.10, 0.90)) 

 library(coda)
    HPDinterval(mcmc(P), 0.90)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both methods user25494 suggests produce inaccurate results. Notice that the distribution is skewed.